# Converting code from vb6 to c#-System.Variant.Marshal Helper Convert Object To Variant'

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, vb6

I have a c++ call to one of the dll like this,

```
public static extern bool RecognizeEvent(int Id ,long DataLength ,ref object EventData);
```

and i am trying to call this function this way..

```
Status = oStatus(parameters);
object oiStatus = (object)Status;
bValue = RecognizeEvent(ID, DataLength, ref oiStatus);
```

where `Status` is a `struct` . when i tried to step through the code i am getting following error

```
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Variant.MarshalHelperConvertObjectToVariant'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
```

I am not sure whether converting struct to object is throwing this exception.
Any kind of pointers will be appreciated

> C#Struct:

```
public struct INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS { 
    public int wMsgId; 
    public int channel; 
    public int unit_id; 
    public int wStatus; 
    public int wRadioStatus; 
    public int wTimeMinutes; 
    public int wPrimarySetID; 
    public int wSecondarySetID; 
    public byte[] individualAlias; 
    public int wZoneId; 
    public int wSiteId; 
    public int dest_unit; 
    public byte[] destinationAlias; 
}
```

> vb 6 struct:

```
Public Type INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS 
    wMsgId As Integer 
    channel As Integer 
    unit_id As Long 
    wStatus As Integer 
    wRadioStatus As Integer 
    wTimeMinutes As Integer 
    wPrimarySetID As Integer 
    wSecondarySetID As Integer 
    individualAlias(0 To 49) As Byte 
    wZoneId As Integer 
    wSiteId As Integer 
    dest_unit As Long 
    destinationAlias(0 To 49) As Byte 
End Type
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the message for the exception was?

Comment: this is exception i am getting Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Variant.MarshalHelperConvertObjectToVariant'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ConsolesTestTool.exe

Comment: Can you post both your C# version of the struct, and the C++ version?

Comment: @Ron Beyer:                                                                                C#Struct public struct INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS
    {
        public int wMsgId;
        public int channel;
        public int unit_id;
        public int wStatus;
        public int wRadioStatus;
        public int wTimeMinutes;
        public int wPrimarySetID;
        public int wSecondarySetID;
        public byte[] individualAlias;
        public int wZoneId;
        public int wSiteId;
        public int dest_unit;
        public byte[] destinationAlias;
    }

Comment: vb 6 struct                                                                                                                         Public Type INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS
    wMsgId As Integer
    channel As Integer
    unit_id As Long
    wStatus As Integer
    wRadioStatus As Integer
    wTimeMinutes As Integer
    wPrimarySetID As Integer
    wSecondarySetID As Integer
    individualAlias(0 To 49) As Byte
    wZoneId As Integer
    wSiteId As Integer
    dest_unit As Long
    destinationAlias(0 To 49) As Byte
End Type

Comment: The C++ code is not actually C++, the VB6 code is not actually VB6.  You'll need to do a better job documenting your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In VB6, `Integer` is actually 2 bytes, so its .NET equivalent type is the `short`. Likewise `Long` is a `int`. You'll also need to specify the size of your arrays since they are fixed size. Your struct in C# should look more like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS
{
    public short wMsgId;
    public short channel;
    public int unit_id;
    public short wStatus;
    public short wRadioStatus;
    public short wTimeMinutes;
    public short wPrimarySetID;
    public short wSecondarySetID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=50)]
    public byte[] individualAlias;
    public short wZoneId;
    public short wSiteId;
    public int dest_unit;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 50)]
    public byte[] destinationAlias;
}
```

Notice the sequential layout attribute at the top, and the specific sized arrays. This should guarantee that the struct is the same layout/size as the VB6 version.

Its also important to note that while `byte` is a value type, `byte[]` is a reference type, and can be `null`. Since you are marshaling the object, its very important that the size of the data you allocate is the same size as the unmanaged code expects.

You may also have to decorate your C# code with some additional attributes, like:

`public static extern bool RecognizeEvent(int Id ,long DataLength ,[Out] ref object EventData);`

The other thing that sticks out to me is that you are passing an `object` in the place of the struct type. This means that you are boxing `INBOUND_RADIO_STATUS`, essentially turning it into a different type. Try using the actual type in its place instead of `object`. Boxing is probably giving you some problems as well and you should know the implications when it comes to passing values between managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: i tried  the new structure definition and exception still exists. Reason for using the object is that i am using different structures to pass to  RecognizeEvent() based on some code like dynamic casting. I am not sure whether dynamic casting causing this exception.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you are wanting, unless the type structure on the unmanaged side changes as well. Without seeing the actual C++ method signature its hard to tell where your problem lies exactly.